# Rabbitmq ignores configuration on Ubuntu 12

Tags: ubuntu, rabbitmq

I have `rabbitmq-server` installed from the system package on **Ubuntu 12**, and no matter what I do it seems to ignore any configuration file.

Everything on the web says the server looks for `/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf`, but even if I create that file the server reports no config:

```
> /usr/sbin/rabbitmq-server 

node           : rabbit@ip-10-160-149-160
app descriptor : /usr/lib/rabbitmq/lib/rabbitmq_server-2.7.1/sbin/../ebin/rabbit.app
home dir       : /var/lib/rabbitmq
config file(s) : (none)
```

I tried setting `RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE` to point to that file, but that has no effect.

Fwiw, my `rabbitmq-env.conf` seems to want to source scripts from `/etc/rabbitmq.conf.d`, but these appear to be expected to be bash scripts, not Erlang config.

Comment: I tried setting CONFIG_FILE in rabbitmq-env.conf to no avail, although setting NODENAME in that file did work, so the server is reading the env file. I tried both "CONFIG_FILE" (correct) and "RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE". Neither one has any effect.

Answer (score 15):

I finally had some luck by just removing `/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf` altogether. I also noticed that the erlang config is rabbitmq.**config** and not 'conf', although fixing that still didn't fix the problem.

Removing `rabbitmq-env.conf` at least allows the server to find `rabbitmq.config`. Good lord, what a mess.

Comment: Also running 2.7.1 (via apt-get) for quick testing. Found this comment helpful, although others may run into other trouble (like "guest" not having permissions for the default vhost).

Answer (score 12):

Setting RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE works, but you are supposed to set it to the filename **without the .config extension**! That means the actual file must have the extension .config.

I wasted quite a lot of time today to figure this out.

Comment: worked here. rabbitmq v3.6.1. 

Also after doing that, you need to do `sudo service rabbitmq-server restart` for those changes to take effect.

and if you're making a config file for the first time for rabbitmq below v3.7.0, use this example config https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/blob/v3.6.x/docs/rabbitmq.config.example

Answer (score 6):

1) RabbitMQ provides an example config file depending upon your distro you can find it in these directories,

```
  Generic UNIX - $RABBITMQ_HOME/etc/rabbitmq/
    Debian - /etc/rabbitmq/
    RPM - /etc/rabbitmq/
    Mac OS X (Macports) - ${install_prefix}/etc/rabbitmq/, the Macports prefix is usually /opt/local
    Windows - %APPDATA%\RabbitMQ\
```

2) To create a configuration file on debian I moved the example file to /etc/rabbitmq directory.

3) renamed rabbitmq.config.example to rabbitmq.config

4) In rabbitmq-env.conf assigned CONFIGFILE variable as a to the path above config file but **without mentioning file extension(.config)**

```
CONFIGFILE=/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq
```

5) Restarted the rabbitmq-server. On debian

```
sudo /etc/init.d/rabbitmq-server start
```

Answer (score 4):

I had success with putting the config in `/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config`. No need to remove `/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf`.

RabbitMQ 2.7.1 on Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1):

in sum
1.tylko rabbitmq.config file without rabbitmq-env.conf works, but need to reset the server:
`/etc/init.d/rabbitmq-server` (start, stop), do not:
  `rabbitmqctl` (stop_app, reset, start_app)
2 rabbitmq.config and rabbitmq-env.conf it may be, but:
in RabbitMQ-env.conf must specify the path:
`CONFIG_FILE = /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq` without config ext!

At least for me :)
Debian 7.0 Rabbit 3.1 erl 1.15

Comment: Thanks. I was clear in the [config docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html) that the env var value should exclude the config ext

Answer (score 0):

in sum 
1. Only rabbitmq.config file without `rabbitmq-env.conf` works, but need to reset the server: `/etc/init.d/rabbitmq-server (start, stop)`, do not:   `rabbitmqctl (stop_app, reset, start_app)` 
2. `rabbitmq.config and rabbitmq-env.conf` it may be, but: in `rabbitmq-env.conf` must specify the path: `CONFIG_FILE = /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq` without config ext!

At least for me :) Debian 7.0 Rabbit 3.1 erl 1.15

Answer (score 0):

1. create rabbitmq-env.conf:
   `echo CONFIG_FILE=/etc/rabbitmq/my-rabbitmq.conf > /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf`
2. download systcl mode config file:
   `wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/master/docs/rabbitmq.conf.example -O /etc/rabbitmq/my-rabbitmq.conf`
3. restart server:
   `systemctl restart rabbitmq-server.service`
4. watch the log change:
   `tail -n 50 /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@rabbitmq.log|head -n 20`
5. see the result
   [my-rabbitmq.conf result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EkL3.png)

---

see more: https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html#customise-environment